# Generalized Circles of Apollonius

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, locus

The locus of points  that have a given ratio of distances
$$k=\frac{d_1}{d_2}$$
to two given points is the [Apollonius circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius).

> What is the locus of points where $$\frac{d_1^a}{d_2}$$ is constant for some $a>0$?

Comment: If $a\in\mathbb{Q}$, then after taking appropriate powers you want $\lvert(z-p_1)^m/(z-p_2)^n\rvert=c$, which is a rational lemniscate.

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you for your comment. Do you know any references on the shape and properties of rational lemniscates?